# Javascript How to add new class without deleting already existing ones

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to add a CSS class when a button is clicked in html using javascript. But i dont want to delete the one that the element already have. For example i have this element

`<div class="one two"></div>`

and i want to add three class so i want the element in the end will be:

`<div class="one two three"></div>`

In my real world problem i have the following code.

HTML:

```
<button id="FileStatusForm:extractButton" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" type="submit" style="margin-right: 10px; opacity: 0.35;" onclick="disableButton(this);return false;" name="FileStatusForm:extractButton" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
```

when i click above button i have to add ui-state-disabled css class

```
.ui-state-disabled{background-image: none;
opacity: 0.35;}
```

I want a solution with vanilla js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [classList.add](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.classList)

JS:

```
function disableButton(x){
      x.classList.add("ui-state-disabled");
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/C6xJr/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
HTMLElementObject.className=classname
```

[W3 School Link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_classname.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
var element = document.getElementById("your_div_id");
element.className = "name_of_ur_class";
```

Answer (score 0):

As some will object to shin's answer that links to w3schools. Here is the mozilla dev network link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.className

Answer (score 0):

```
function btnclick()
{
      var txt=document.getElementId("<%=txt.ClientID%>");
      txt.className="classname";
}
```

or use the following jquery

```
$("#txt").addClass("classname");
$("#txt").removeClass("classname");
```